# Steps to consider during planning of new project

Tags: project-planning

What are the points I must remember during the planning phase of the project to have a really firm foundation?

Thanks

Edit: I mean more specifically related to coding. (I don't mean the budgets etc etc).

For example: Where can we use generics,reflection or concepts in C#

Comment: You need to be more specific.  A project with one person working on a one-off tool that needs to constantly evolve requires much different planning than a mission critical application being built by 5000 people.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: You *need* to read a few books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the planning phase you need to:

1. Define the problem your solving
2. Validate the problem actually exists
3. Define a solution with your customer
   (This is more of a starting point, I
   recommend constant user feedback
   into your lifecycle but you need to
   start somewhere)
4. Define the scope of the project, including features, cost / budget and time

Answer (score 1):

Communicate..Communicate..Communicate..

Comment: actually I didn't ask the question we have lots of Joshs here it seems

Answer (score 0):

1) Know your deadlines
2) Know your budget

If you let either one of these get away on you, you are setting yourself up for a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Steve McConnell's book on Software Estimation. It will help you consider all area's before getting started. For if you have to estimate it then you should know what has to be done.

You should also consider reading Code Complete.

[Software Estimations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735605351), [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)